# Select edge after boolean difference to bevel?

Tags: mesh, edges, bevel, boolean-modifier

I have a shape extruded from an imported svg that has been converted to mesh then modified with a boolean difference so that there can be a slight tapering curve to the extrusion.

I would like to bevel the edges now, however, I cannot select the top edge (boolean difference side) which is where I want my bevel. The bottom edge can still be selected and a boolean modifier can be added. How can I bevel the top edge?

Doing limited dissolve drastically changes my geometry.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, don't forget to apply the scale of your objects in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*), otherwise the bevel won't work proportionally.

Select all, press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view), it will get rid of the edge loops that are cutting your top face, then you'll be able to bevel.

For your new object, select one of the bad faces, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>
<kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Normal*, tweak the *Threshold* in the *Operator* box until it selects all the wanted faces, and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* again.

You'll need to create some transversal edges to have a good bevel:

[image]

Then select the rim edges (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left Click</kbd> to select between two edges) and bevel.

Comment: Hi! This worked for the original example, however, I have another with more complex top geometry [picture added to original post]. When I do the limited dissolve, it drastically changes the geometry. Is there still a way to select to bevel?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please share your new object?

Comment: added the file!

Comment: For your new object, select one of the bad faces, press Shift G (Select Similar) > Normal, tweak the Threshold in the Operator box until it selects all the wanted faces, and X > Limited Dissolve again.

Comment: Also don't forget to apply the scale of your objects in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: thank you, you're amazing!